# Can't get my location in the app map

Tags: java, android

Included in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

The activity code:

```
public class ActivityLogin extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static LocationManager mLocationManager;
    public static MyLocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

    //...

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // ...
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(ActivityLogin.this,
            new String[] {
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            },
            2);
        // ...

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
        String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case 2:
                {
                    // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                    if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, 0, locationListener);
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, 0, locationListener);
                        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.PASSIVE_PROVIDER, 10 * 1000, 0, locationListener);
                    }
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
     public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
         MapsActivity.Mylocation = new LatLng(
             location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
     }

     public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
         // ...
     }

     public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
         // ...
         Location location = ActivityLogin.mLocationManager
             .getLastKnownLocation(provider);
         if (location != null) {
             MapsActivity.Mylocation = new LatLng(
                 location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
         }
     }

     public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
         // ...    
     }
 }
```

As a result, the event `onLocationChanged` doesn't occur. If I am switching wifi off and then on again, the event `onProviderEnabled` occurs and `ActivityLogin.mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider)` returns `null`.

In the end, I can't get my coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I have had trouble with the locationListener in the past and the only way I got it working was by implementing the LocationListener in the mainActivity, a local or silent locationlistener would just not work.

eg

```
public class ActivityLogin extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener
```

That said, google is deprecating the locationListener and replacing it with the Google location API. This uses the fusedLocationAPI with an GoogleApiClient.

In your onCreate you should have something like

```
GoogleApiClient api_client;

 api_client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
```

In your onConnected method you should have something like

```
location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(api_client);
```

I do not think it is an improvement but google are forcing this on us.